# Bind Visibility of Textblock with Boolean not working

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) App**. I used a **ListView** to populate items:

**XAML:**

```
xmlns:ConvertersFile="using:DrFit.Converters"

<Page.Resources>
       <ConvertersFile:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="EquipmentListView" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="EquipmentListView_SelectionChanged">                    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
                <Grid>      
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EquipmentDetails}"                  
                        x:Name="EquipmentDetails"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowHide, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>>
                        </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**C# Class For ListView:**

```
 class EquipmentClassTemporary
    {
        public string EquipmentTitle { get; set; }    
        public string EquipmentDetails { get; set; }
        public bool ShowHide { get; set; }

    }
```

**C#:**

```
ObservableCollection<EquipmentClassTemporary> EquipmentListViewList = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentClassTemporary>();
private void GenerateEquipmentListView()
{
    for(int i=0; i< SingletonInstance.strHeading.Length;i++)
    {
        EquipmentListViewList.Add(new EquipmentClassTemporary { EquipmentTitle = SingletonInstance.strHeading[i], EquipmentDetails = SingletonInstance.strEquipment[i],  ShowHide=false });
    }
    EquipmentListView.ItemsSource = EquipmentListViewList;
}

private void EquipmentListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var ClickedItem = e.AddedItems[0];
        ((EquipmentClassTemporary)ClickedItem).ShowHide = true;
    }

    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var UnClickedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
        ((EquipmentClassTemporary)UnClickedItem).ShowHide = false;

    }
}
```

**BoolToVisConverter:**

```
public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
}
```

The Visibility of EquipmentDetails Textblock is not getting changed.?

Comment: can you try implementing INotifyPropertychanged for the property ShowHide

Comment: Can you please help me in INotifyPropertychanged?

Comment: You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your item class (`EquipmentClassTemporary`). Currently when you change `ShowHide` auto-property value nothing tells the view to update the item bindings. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524977/1997232) answer (it also does it with neat `CallerMemberName` attribute).

Comment: @ Atif Shabeer please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the following code to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

then call OnPropertyChanged from the property setter like

```
    private bool showHide;

    public bool ShowHide
    {
        get { return showHide; }
        set { showHide = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ShowHide"); }
    }
```

Comment: I also have an Image source as string:

Comment: public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return imageSource; }
            set
            {
                imageSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        }

Comment: Do I need to use two PropertyChangedEventHandler and two OnPropertyChanged methods?

Answer (score 0):

Once the propertyChanged event handler is registered, you can use many properties in that class. No need of separate "OnPropertyChanged" functions.

```
public bool ShowHide
{
    get { return showHide; }
    set { showHide = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ShowHide"); }
}

public int newProperty
{
    get { return _newProperty; }
    set { _newProperty = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("newProperty"); }
}

public string NewStringProp
{
    get { return _NewStringProp; }
    set { _NewStringProp = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("NewStringProp"); }
}
```

and so on...